# GA360 unsampled report into bigQuery

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery, google-analytics-api

I've created an automatic daily unsampled report on my Google Analytics 360.

I want to send the report to my BigQuery project and the only option I have for getting the report is via mail with a link.

Is there any way I can send the report automatically to BigQuery?

The report contains a list of **one custom dimension values**, **count of users** and **count of sessions** -  in a segment that uses the user bucket dimension.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can export data automatically from Analytics 360 to BigQuery with the **BigQuery Export**: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en

But you cannot send a custom report from Google Analytics to BigQuery.

Anyway you can write data to BQ programmatically using **BigQuery API**: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest
In other words, you can use the Google Analytics API (Reporting or Unsampled API) to replicate the query of your report and the BigQuery API to write the result in a table.

You can use **Google Apps Script** which has an integrated system with APIs and makes your work easier.

Comment: I know I can export data and I am. That's why I mentioned the report contains a segment, which I dont have on the export. and the segment is using user bucket, which I also dont have in the export

Comment: Great, but the solution is using the BQ API, the other part you haven't mentioned in your comment.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I think you didn't understand my question.

Comment: I update my answer to better specify the context. I have indicated that of the API as a solution since you cannot send a custom report directly from Google Analytics to BigQuery. This seemed to me your question, then I may have been wrong.

Comment: That exactly what I eventually did. For some reason it's much easier to send custom report than unsampled report. Still working on the solution in apps scripts. Thank you again for your answers:)